# Is there an easy way to convert 11.04 wubi install to a new partititon with no drawback?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, conversion, migration, wubi

I have a wubi install that is running great. Some of the setup though is pretty time intensive, and I didn't realize that WUBI was only meant for testing - I thought it would be equally as good as the regular installation :( So, I'd like to transfer my entire installation and move it to a new partition - with new swap partition and all.

Is there an easy way to do that? I tried looking at lvpm (or lpvm.. i forget), but Ubuntu 11.04 complains that it is low quality software. Is it safe?

Should I just install a fresh copy of 11.04 anyway? What are the drawbacks to using something like lvpm?

Should I just keep the wubi installation and not care?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LVPM is by the same people who did wubi, It worked fine before, but apparently [dosen't work with newer versions](http://lubi.sourceforge.net/lvpm.html) - which is probably why ubuntu complains about it.

If you REALLY need to be able to suspend/resume or something else ubuntu needs, switch over to a real partition. Else, really, if it works, there's no need to fix it, IMO

You can probably reinstall ubuntu fresh, and move over your home directory if you really want a physical install of it.

Comment: besides suspend/resume... what other things would I be missing? Would there be a big performance increase if I went with a fresh install? Anything of that nature? I am mainly programming when I am in Linux. I've already accidentally hit the suspend button and that was not fun :/

Comment: I can't really remember, I think that, and needing to shut it down PROPERLY to avoid bad things (tm) happening were the main issues i had.

Comment: I think I've had "bad things (tm)" happen to me already. Sometimes I boot into Ubuntu and the minimize/maximum buttons don't load up properly when I boot in sometimes. Other-times, I don't have sound (using an FA-66 audo hardware box) This sound problem is simply fixed by rebooting again :/

Comment: i've had sound issues on vanilla kubuntu installs before as well, you need to look up the command for restarting just the audio subsystem - in my case it was 'sudo alsa force-reload

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

No special skills needed.

There is a script to do it, and also an outstanding [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1519354) that not only tells you what to do but also helps you in understanding what is being done.